# Get GridView row index from a template field button

Tags: c#, asp.net

first question:

I have a gridview 'gvSnacks' with a list of snacks and prices. The first column of the gridview is a templatefield with the button 'btnAdd'.

When one of the add buttons is clicked I want it to assign that rows value to an integer so I can retrieve additional data from that row.

This is what I have, but I've hit a dead end.

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int intRow = gvSnacks.SelectedRow.RowIndex;

    string strDescription = gvSnacks.Rows[intRow].Cells[2].Text;
    string strPrice = gvSnacks.Rows[intRow].Cells[3].Text;
}
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Question is how do I assign the gridview row to an integer when clicking one of the Add buttons?

Comment: what's wrong with your current code?

Comment: If you are new in asp I suggest to spend your time learning to use ListView instead GridView. In my opinion they are much more powerful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to use the RowCommand Event :

```
public event GridViewCommandEventHandler RowCommand
```

[This is the MSDN link for this event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx).

The button must have the CommandName attribute and you can put the value of the row in the command argument :

```
 void ContactsGridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {
    // If multiple buttons are used in a GridView control, use the
    // CommandName property to determine which button was clicked.
    if(e.CommandName=="Add")
    {
      // Convert the row index stored in the CommandArgument
      // property to an Integer.
      int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

      // Retrieve the row that contains the button clicked 
      // by the user from the Rows collection.
      GridViewRow row = ContactsGridView.Rows[index];

      // Create a new ListItem object for the contact in the row.     
      ListItem item = new ListItem();
      item.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[2].Text) + " " +
        Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[3].Text);

      // If the contact is not already in the ListBox, add the ListItem 
      // object to the Items collection of the ListBox control. 
      if (!ContactsListBox.Items.Contains(item))
      {
        ContactsListBox.Items.Add(item);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Appreciate this! I'm really liking the ability to handle different arguments under one rowcommand!